# how to add @carbon/type in nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Im using @carbon/vue in a nuxt application and have created a plugin which i registered in my nuxt.config.js file. I am now trying to incorporate @carbon/type for fonts but it is not getting pulled in. How do i add carbon/type in nuxt?

`carbon.js`

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import "carbon-components/css/carbon-components.css";
import CarbonComponentsVue from "@carbon/vue";
Vue.use(CarbonComponentsVue);
```

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
plugins: [
    { src: '~plugins/pubnub.js', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~plugins/axios.js', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~plugins/auth.js', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~plugins/vue-instantsearch.js' },
    { src: '~plugins/carbon.js', mode:'client' }
],
```

Comment: What is not working here? Do you have some errors?

Comment: i actually dont get any errors but when i try and use     <div class="bx--type-productive-heading-06">Welcome to</div> it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Hello please check your other files

In your `src/App.vue` did you import

```
<style lang="scss">
@import "./styles/carbon";
</style>
```

In your `src/styles/_carbon.scss` did you import

```
@import 'carbon-components/scss/globals/scss/styles';
```